# how to use rxplot to plot data on /tf

Tags: ros, pose, rxplot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

How to use rxplot to plot the transforms?
They have the position and orientation.

Example

header:
seq: 0
stamp:
secs: 1311867210
nsecs: 774027961
frame_id: /world
child_frame_id: /kinect
transform:
translation:
x: 0.208460861206
y: -1.06889804077
z: 1.87455181885
rotation:
x: -0.0425775370706
y: -0.0287192089576
z: 0.77849649613
w: 0.625544215773

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58793/how-to-use-rxplot-to-plot-data-on-/tf/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my opinion, **rxplot** is not the best tool at plotting tf's. I would recommend you to use **rviz** for that.

If you want to see x, y and z positions and orientations maybe you should consider using an odometry or pose topic parsed from the node tf or something similar, in order to avoid what Adolfo Rodríguez comments.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-04-03**:
There is no "best tool", as the goodness measure depends a lot on your requirements. Rviz excels at visualizing instantaneous frame configurations, but if you're interested in visualizing time series a plotting tool might be more appropriate.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-04-03**:
...additionally the details of a specific implementation can make your life easier or harder. Plotting  a /tf time series with rxplot/rqt has its difficulties, but plotting a pose_stamped topic is straightforward. YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following snippet will print the x coordinate of the first transform in a tf message:

```
rxplot /tf/transforms[0]/transform/translation/x
```

**Big caveat:** if there are multiple publishers of the /tf topic, this won't work, as the transform vector index (the [0] above) will not always represent the same frame. Further, f you're querying a nonzero index, it might be possible that the index does not even exist in a given message.

I would recommend republishing the transform(s) of interest as a separate pose(stamped) message and plot from there. More overhead, but less surprises.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2